# Passing a NULL value to a PHP function

Tags: php

I have a function like:

```
function do_something($first, $second=null, $third=null) { 

    if ($isset($second)) {

        // Do something here

    }

}
```

Now, I want to pass a value for `$third` to the function, but I want `$second` to remain NULL:

```
do_something('abc','','def');
```

Now, `$second` is no longer NULL. How can I pass a value for `$third` while leaving `$second` NULL?

Comment: `do_something('abc',null,'def');`

Comment: `do_something('abc', null, 'def');`

Comment: You mean the second argument still null?

Comment: Well you could instead use the arguments such `$first` to signify mandatory and pass an`$option = array()` and proceed with the logic instead. But basically if u plan on providing that function with a lot of data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no other way:

```
do_something('abc', null,'def');
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is quite easy to do this:

```
do_something('abc', null,'def');
```

Otherwise, I am linking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029404/php-optional-parameters-specify-parameter-value-by-name) SO question which uses array arguments, in order to have optional arguments (credits to sanmai - I'd take no credit for this):

```
function do_something($arguments = array()) {
// set defaults
    $arguments = array_merge(array(
        "argument" => "default value", 
    ), $arguments); 

    var_dump($arguments);
}
```

With example usage:

```
do_something(); // with all defaults, or:
do_something(array("argument" => "other value"));
```

Comment: My favored option, much cleaner, id use `extract` with that.