# Passing named parameters to a php function through call_user_func_array

Tags: php, function

When trying to call a function in a child class with an arbitrary set of parameters, I'm having the following problem:

```
class Base{

    function callDerived($method,$params){
        call_user_func_array(array($this,$method),$params);
    }
}

class Derived extends Base{
    function test($foo,$bar){
        print "foo=$foo, bar=$bar\n";
    }
}

$d = new Derived();
$d->callDerived('test',array('bar'=>'2','foo'=>1));
```

Outputs:

```
foo=2, bar=1
```

Which... is not exactly what I wanted - is there a way to achieve this *beyond* re-composing the array with the index order of func_get_args? And yes, of course, I could simply pass the whole array and deal with it in the function... but that's not what I want to do.

Thanks

Comment: I think you are out of luck here...

Comment: No way. Also it feels uncomfortable, that you don't know the order of the arguments of your own methods :X Maybe you should consider using `interface`s, if you want to _ensure_ a specific order.

Comment: @KingCrunch Actually, what I'm unsure of is the order of the array of params I get - but yes, this is a kludgy situation.

Comment: @Wagemage: Maybe you just don't need `call_user_func_array()`:  `call_user_func('func', $array['foo'], $array['bar']);`?

Comment: @KingCrunch Yeah, I see what you mean - but for different Derived classes the invocation will have a different number and order of parameters... it's a kludge that I'm trying to de-pessimize, not brand-spaking-new code I'm trying to write.

Comment: I shared a Q/A as a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56415163

Comment: It is possible now in PHP 8.0. You must only make small change and use spread operator (`...`) to your code. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64072408/7082164

Comment: @Wag I haven't tried with `call_user_func_array()`, but the earliest asked question on the topic of "named parameters" was in 2009 and contains [a comprehensive/generous answer posted 2020-11-25 (the day before the new feature was deployed with PHP8.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64997399/2943403). I consider this page to be the "canonical" on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No. PHP does not support named parameters. Only the order of parameters is taken into account. You could probably take the code itself apart using the [ReflectionClass](http://php.net/reflectionclass) to inspect the function parameter names, but in the end you'd need to use this to reorder the array anyway.

Comment: Yeah, was afraid of that. Oh well... aesthetics be damned, I can deal with it through the func_get_args stuff.

Comment: Now named parameters support in [PHP 8](https://stitcher.io/blog/php-8-named-arguments) :)

Answer (score 8):

The stock PHP class **ReflectionMethod** is your friend.

Example:

```
class MyClass { 
    function myFunc($param1, $param2, $param3='myDefault') { 
        print "test"; 
    } 
}

$refm = new ReflectionMethod('MyClass', 'myFunc');

foreach ($refm->getParameters() as $p) 
    print "$p\n";
```

And the result:

```
Parameter #0 [ <required> $param1 ]
Parameter #1 [ <required> $param2 ]
Parameter #2 [ <optional> $param3 = 'myDefault' ]
```

At this point you know the names of the parameters of the target function. With this information you can modify your method '*callDerived*', and you can re-order the array to **call_user_func_array** according to the parameter names.

Answer (score 5):

Good news, I had the same concern (I was looking for named arguments in PHP, like Python does), and found this useful tool : https://github.com/PHP-DI/Invoker

This uses the reflection API to feed a callable with some arguments from an array and also use optional arguments defaults for other parameters that are not defined in the array.

```
$invoker = new Invoker\Invoker;
$result = $invoker->call(array($object, 'method'), array(
    "strName"  => "Lorem",
    "strValue" => "ipsum",
    "readOnly" => true,
    "size"     => 55,
));
```

Have fun

Comment: DownVote: That's not called "named arguments". That's just passing a map to function. Named arguments will support code completion, reflection, ...

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE**: PHP 8 Now supports named parameters. And it works with `call_user_func_array` if you pass an associative array. So you can simply do this:

```php
<?php

function myFunc($foo, $bar) {
    echo "foo=$foo, bar=$bar\n";
}

call_user_func_array('myFunc', ['bar' => 2, 'foo' => 1]);
// Outputs:  foo=1, bar=2
```

In your code, you'll be happy to know that you don't have to change a thing. Just upgrade to PHP 8 and it'll work as you expected

Answer (score 3):

You can simply pass an array and extract:

```
function add($arr){
    extract($arr, EXTR_REFS);
    return $one+$two;
}
$one = 1;
$two = 2;
echo add(compact('one', 'two')); // 3
```

This will extract as references, so there is close to no overhead.

Answer (score 3):

I use a bitmask instead of boolean parameters:

```
// Ingredients
define ('TOMATO',    0b0000001);
define ('CHEESE',    0b0000010);
define ('OREGANO',   0b0000100);
define ('MUSHROOMS', 0b0001000);
define ('SALAMI',    0b0010000);
define ('PEPERONI',  0b0100000);
define ('ONIONS',    0b1000000);

function pizza ($ingredients) {
  $serving = 'Pizza with';
  $serving .= ($ingredients&TOMATO)?' Tomato':''; 
  $serving .= ($ingredients&CHEESE)?' Cheese':''; 
  $serving .= ($ingredients&OREGANO)?' Oregano':''; 
  $serving .= ($ingredients&MUSHROOMS)?' Mushrooms':''; 
  $serving .= ($ingredients&SALAMI)?' Salami':''; 
  $serving .= ($ingredients&ONIONS)?' Onions':''; 
  return trim($serving)."\n" ;
}

// Now order your pizzas!
echo pizza(TOMATO | CHEESE | SALAMI); 
echo pizza(ONIONS | TOMATO | MUSHROOMS | CHEESE); // "Params" are not positional
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who still might stumble on the question (like I did), here is my approach:

since **PHP 5.6** you can use **...** as mentioned [here](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list.new):

In this case you could use something like this:

```
class Base{

    function callDerived($method,...$params){
            call_user_func_array(array($this,$method),$params);
        }
}

class Derived extends Base{
    function test(...$params){
        foreach ($params as $arr) {
            extract($arr);
        }
        print "foo=$foo, bar=$bar\n";
    }
}

$d = new Derived();
$d->callDerived('test',array('bar'=>'2'),array('foo'=>1)); 

//print: foo=1, bar=2
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it and is using arrays (the most easy way):

```
class Test{
    public $a  = false;
    private $b = false;
    public $c  = false;
    public $d  = false;
    public $e  = false;
    public function _factory(){
        $args    = func_get_args();
        $args    = $args[0];
        $this->a = array_key_exists("a",$args) ? $args["a"] : 0;
        $this->b = array_key_exists("b",$args) ? $args["b"] : 0;
        $this->c = array_key_exists("c",$args) ? $args["c"] : 0;
        $this->d = array_key_exists("d",$args) ? $args["d"] : 0;
        $this->e = array_key_exists("e",$args) ? $args["e"] : 0;
    }
    public function show(){
        var_dump($this);
    }
}

$test = new Test();
$args["c"]=999;
$test->_factory($args);
$test->show();
```

a full explanation can be found in my blog:
http://www.tbogard.com/2013/03/07/passing-named-arguments-to-a-function-in-php/

Comment: Srly ? Hope you'll never mess-up with something like `$this->e = array_key_exists("d",$args) ? $args["e"] : 0;`, will be so time-consuming to debug... BTW you're using 7 lines of code just to save a few parameters while calling your function ? Clearly not worth it.