# PHP Call static function in string

Tags: php, function, model-view-controller, static, call

I'm creating my own MVC framework with my own routes engine. 
When I call a page, my URL is like that : http://www.domain.com/lang/controller/method/

Everything is ok with this configuration but when I send parameters by POST, I want them in my function declaration. 
For example :
`$_POST => Array ( [login] => myLogin, [pwd] => myPassword)` for the function `ConnectUser($login, $password).`

My controller is a singleton. So, my function call is like that : `\core\controller\UserController::getInstance()->ConnectUser($login, $password).`

I generate my call in a string. When I do

```
$funcCall = $strCall . "::getInstance()->" . $_GET['action'] . "()";
forward_static_call_array($funcCall, $_POST);
```

I get this error :

```
forward_static_call_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
class 'core\controller\UserController' does not have a method 'getInstance()->Connect()'
```

Do you have an idea on my problem?

Comment: It is very clear.. your method is called `ConnectUser` and your action is only `Connect`

Comment: It was a mistake when I copy-pasted my code. :)

Answer (score 1):

1. `"core\controller\UserController::getInstance()->Connect()"` is not a valid callback

   - Example of a valid callback in your case would be this:

     ```
     $funcCall = [$strCall::getInstance(), $_GET['action']];
     ```

     See [PHP docs - Callbacks / Callables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).
2. You should use [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) instead of `forward_static_call_array()` since you aren't calling static methods <sub><sup>(and even if you were you likely aren't calling them from a context where it would matter).</sup></sub>
3. `$_POST` will not get magically mapped to the method's arguments by name. You'd have to use reflection for that. See [Passing named parameters to a php function through call_user_func_array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610556/passing-named-parameters-to-a-php-function-through-call-user-func-array)