# Passing an array through a PHP function

Tags: php, function

Im sure there has to be a way to do this:

I want it so that If I call a function like this...

```
callFunction("var1","var2","var3");
```

the function 'callFunction' will turn these variables into an array i.e:

```
$array[0] = "var1";
$array[1] = "var2";
$array[2] = "var3";
```

I want it to generate this array no matter how many variables are listed when calling the function, is this possible?

Comment: [`func_get_args()`](http://us.php.net/func_get_args)?

Comment: Is the question now, whether and how to pass an array to a function, or whether a function can be called with variable number of arguments?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `array` ???

Comment: @Havelock - I interpret it as "how to declare a varaidic function which will put all of its arguments into an array". If that is the case, don't roll your own, use `array()`. If you want to do more, do as @DCoder says and use `func_get_args()`.

Comment: This page in the manual might be insightful for you, too: [Variable-length argument lists](http://us.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Function Argument to an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7603517/php-function-argument-to-an-array)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply do the following:

```
function callFunction() {
    $arr = func_get_args();
    // Do something with all the arguments
    // e.g. $arr[0], ...
}
```

[`func_get_args`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) will return all the parameters passed to a function. You don't even need to specify them in the function header.

[`func_num_args`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php) will yield the number of arguments passed to the function. I'm not entirely sure why such a thing exists, given that you can simple `count(func_get_args())`, but I suppose it exist because it does in C (where it is actually necessary).

If you ever again look for this kind of feature in a different language, it is usually referred to as [Variadic Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function), or "varargs" if you need to Google it quickly :)

Comment: @George you would need to add `return $arg;`

Answer (score 0):

Just return `func_get_args()` from that function:

```
function callFunction(){
    return func_get_args();
}

$array = callFunction("var1","var2","var3","var4","var5");
var_dump($array);

/*array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "var1"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "var2"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "var3"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "var4"
  [4]=>
  string(4) "var5"
}*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Call your function like this.

```
callFunction( array("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5") );
```

and create your function like this.

```
function callFunction($array)
{
    //here you can acces your array. no matter how many variables are listed when calling the function.
    print_r($array);
}
```